# Google Webscraper (URLS) - including more than the first page in results

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Got a basic Google webscraper that returns urls of the first google search page - I want it to include URLS on further pages. What's the best way to paginate this code so as it grabs URLS from pages 2,3,4,5,6,7 etc.

Don't want to go off into space with how many pages I scrap but definitely want more than the first page !

```
import requests
import urllib
import pandas as pd
from requests_html import HTML
from requests_html import HTMLSession


def get_source(url):
    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        response = session.get(url)
        return response

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)


def scrape_google(query):

    query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
    response = get_source("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + query)

    links = list(response.html.absolute_links)
    google_domains = ('https://www.google.',
                      'https://google.',
                      'https://webcache.googleusercontent.',
                      'http://webcache.googleusercontent.',
                      'https://policies.google.',
                      'https://support.google.',
                      'https://maps.google.')

    for url in links[:]:
        if url.startswith(google_domains):
            links.remove(url)

    return links

print(scrape_google('https://www.google.com/search?q=letting agent'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over a specific `range()` and set the start parameter by multiply the number of iteration by 10 - Save your results to a `list` and use `set()` to remove duplicates:

```
data = []

for i in range(3):
    data.extend(scrape_google('letting agent', i*10))

set(data)
```

#### Example

```
import requests

def scrape_google(query,start):

    response = get_source(f"https://www.google.co.uk/search?q={query}&start={start}")

    links = list(response.html.absolute_links)
    google_domains = ('https://www.google.',
                      'https://google.',
                      'https://webcache.googleusercontent.',
                      'http://webcache.googleusercontent.',
                      'https://policies.google.',
                      'https://support.google.',
                      'https://maps.google.')

    for url in links[:]:
        if url.startswith(google_domains):
            links.remove(url)

    return links
    
data = []

for i in range(3):
    data.extend(scrape_google('letting agent', i*10))

print(set(data))
```

#### Output

```
{'https://www.lettingagenttoday.co.uk/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://howsy.com/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.propertymark.co.uk/professional-standards/consumer-guides/landlords/what-does-a-letting-agent-do.html&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/housing/renting-privately/during-your-tenancy/complaining-about-your-letting-agent/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.allagents.co.uk/find-agent/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.theonlinelettingagents.co.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://www.which.co.uk/money/mortgages-and-property/buy-to-let/using-a-letting-agent-a16lu1w364rv', 'https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/non-resident-landord-guidance-notes-for-letting-agents-and-tenants-non-resident-landlords-scheme-guidance-notes', 'https://lettingagentregistration.gov.scot/renew', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letting_agent#Services_and_fees', 'https://patriciashepherd.co.uk/', 'https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/letting%20agent', 'https://www.diamonds-salesandlettings.co.uk/', 'https://www.lettingagentproperties.com/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.ukala.org.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://register.lettingagentregistration.gov.scot/search&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-deutsch/letting+agent', 'https://www.cubittandwest.co.uk/landlord-guides/what-is-a-letting-agent/', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letting_agent', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://safeagents.co.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://charlesroseproperties.co.uk/news/letting-agent-vs-estate-agent-the-differences/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://www.tenantshop.co.uk/letting-agents/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://lettingagentregistration.gov.scot/renew&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.winkworth.co.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://objego.de/lp-immobilienverwaltung/', 'https://www.facebook.com/agestateagents/videos/looking-to-instruct-a-letting-agent-not-sure-what-you-should-be-looking-for-or-w/688390845096579/', 'https://www.ukala.org.uk/', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letting_agent#Regulation', 'https://www.foxtons.co.uk/', 'https://ibizaprestige.com/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.which.co.uk/money/mortgages-and-property/buy-to-let/using-a-letting-agent-a16lu1w364rv&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.tenantshop.co.uk/letting-agents/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://www.dict.cc/?s=letting+agent', 'https://www.landlordaccreditationscotland.com/letting-agent-training/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/non-resident-landord-guidance-notes-for-letting-agents-and-tenants-non-resident-landlords-scheme-guidance-notes&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.propertyinvestmentsuk.co.uk/what-is-a-letting-agent/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://www.propertyinvestmentsuk.co.uk/what-is-a-letting-agent/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.leaders.co.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letting_agent&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://www.allagents.co.uk/find-agent/', 'https://www.leaders.co.uk/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.foxtons.co.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://howsy.com/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://patriciashepherd.co.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.lettingagenttoday.co.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://register.lettingagentregistration.gov.scot/search', 'https://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/letting+agent.html', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.diamonds-salesandlettings.co.uk/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://www.theonlinelettingagents.co.uk/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.lettingagentproperties.com/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'http://www.paul-partner.com/', 'https://www.homeday.de/de/homeday-makler/rhein-main-gebiet-sued/?utm_medium=seo&utm_source=gmb&utm_campaign=rhein_main_gebiet_sued', 'https://www.propertymark.co.uk/professional-standards/consumer-guides/landlords/what-does-a-letting-agent-do.html', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/housing/renting-privately/during-your-tenancy/complaining-about-your-letting-agent/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://safeagents.co.uk/', 'https://charlesroseproperties.co.uk/news/letting-agent-vs-estate-agent-the-differences/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.landlordaccreditationscotland.com/letting-agent-training/&prev=search&pto=aue', 'https://move.uk.net/', 'https://www.winkworth.co.uk/', 'https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=https://www.cubittandwest.co.uk/landlord-guides/what-is-a-letting-agent/&prev=search&pto=aue'}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape Google Search Results using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library without the need to use `requests-html`.

To extract all the results from all possible pages dynamically, we need to use [`while` loop with a specific condition to exit the loop](https://python.plainenglish.io/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#74dc). It will go through all of them no matter how many pages there're. Basically, we don't hardcode page numbers to go from N to N pages.

In this case, pagination is possible as long as the next button exists (determined by the presence of a button selector on the page, in our case the CSS selector `.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]`, you need to increase the value of ["start"] by 10 to access the next page ([non-token pagination](https://python.plainenglish.io/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#5a76)), if present, otherwise, we need to exit the while loop:

```py
if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
    params["start"] += 10
else:
    break
```

Google, like other sites, may block your request thinking you are a bot if you use `requests`, since the default user-agent library in `requests` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814).

To avoid it, one of the steps could be to [rotate `user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on. The most reliable way is to use rotating proxies, user-agents, and a captcha solver.

Check code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-search-results-of-all-pages-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "letting agent",  # query
    "hl": "en",            # language
    "gl": "uk",            # country of the search, UK -> United Kingdom
    "start": 0,            # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100            # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

page_num = 0

website_data = []

while True:
    page_num += 1
    print(f"page: {page_num}")
        
    html = requests.get("https://www.google.co.uk/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    
    for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
        title = result.select_one(".DKV0Md").text
        website_link = result.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]
        try:
            snippet = result.select_one(".lEBKkf span").text
        except:
            None
                    
        website_data.append({
              "title": title,
              "snippet": snippet,
              "website_link": website_link  
        })
      
    if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break

print(json.dumps(website_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Letting agents in York Anderton McClements. Luxury Lets in ...",
    "snippet": "Anderton McClements are the Letting Agents in York. We offer the best possible service in property letting in York. Contact us today.",
    "website_link": "https://andertonmcclements.co.uk/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Letting Agents near Swansea | Reviews - Yell",
    "snippet": "Search for Letting Agents near you, or submit your own review. ... an experienced letting agent can help you discover your next property to let.",
    "website_link": "https://www.yell.com/s/letting+agents-swansea.html"
  },
  other results...
]
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json, os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), # serpapi key from https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
  "engine": "google",              # serpapi parser engine
  "q": "letting agent",            # search query
  "gl": "uk",                      # country of the search, UK -> United Kingdom
  "num": "100"                     # number of results per page (100 per page in this case)
  # other search parameters: https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)      # where data extraction happens

organic_results_data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()    # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "title": result.get("title"),
            "snippet": result.get("snippet"),
            "link": result.get("link")
        })
    
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "title": "Appeal to private landlords to offer tenancy to those in need",
    "snippet": "“If you are unsure if your property will be suitable, please call us to discuss and if you are a landlord who uses a letting agent and would ...",
    "link": "https://newsroom.shropshire.gov.uk/2022/12/appeal-to-private-landlords-to-offer-tenancy-to-those-in-need/"
  },
  other results...
]
```